# Опасен ли Type Punning в WinAPI? C++

Tags: c++, winapi, неопределённое-поведение

В *WinAPI* можно ОЧЕНЬ часто встретить код, где используется [type punning](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#:%7E:text=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%20%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20(%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB.%20type%20punning),%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0) для передачи параметров или получения результата. Яркий пример:

```
RECT GetWindowPos() const
{
  RECT rect{};
  if (GetClientRect(m_windowHandle, &rect))
  {
    if (MapWindowPoints(m_windowHandle, NULL, 
                        (LPPOINT)(&rect), 2)) // <=
    {
      return rect;
    }
  }
  // ....
  return rect;
}
```

То есть мы объект воспринимаем, как набор байтов, кастуя указатель на него к другому типу, после чего работаем с ним, как с новым типом. Насколько я знаю, **type punning** не поддерживается стандартом по-умолчанию и может привести к **undefined behavior**, особенно если у изначального типа есть [Indeterminate value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423673/what-is-indeterminate-value).

Вопрос: насколько опасен в *WinAPI* используемый повсеместно в нём **type punning** и стоит ли заменять его в коде выше на более безопасный вариант с memcpy? Да, это более безопасно, но приводит к копированию, что может вызвать замедление там, где это не нужно.

```
RECT GetWindowPos() const
{
  RECT rect{};
  if (GetClientRect(m_windowHandle, &rect))
  {
    POINT coords[2]{};
    memcpy_s(&coords, sizeof(coords), &rect, sizeof(rect));
    if (MapWindowPoints(m_windowHandle, NULL, coords, 2))
    {
      memcpy_s(&rect, sizeof(rect), &coords, sizeof(coords));
      return rect;
    }
  }
  // ....
  return rect;
}
```

Comment: грубое приведение типов опасно тем, что любое изменение в новой версии библиотеки **не** вызывает никаких предупреждений компилятора. И будет пахать до часа Х.

Comment: Все эти рассуждения об опасности и UB являются следствием мифа о переносимости программ. А ведь каждый компилятор (и даже его новая версия)  для каждой архитектуры может иметь свои особенности, которые ломают переносимость. Реально (если вы пишете **серьезную программу**), всегда надо тщательно ее отлаживать на каждой из пар компилятор-архитектура (иногда вплоть до просмотра вывода дизассемблера (objdump)). Т.е. правильней всего считать перенос написанием новой программы с выбором новых ключей компиляции для разных компонент.

Comment: Прочитал комментарии, но так и не услышал внятного ответа: стоит ли применять "обычный" стиль каста в WinAPI , использующий type punning, или же лучше использовать memcpy?

Comment: @AlexF нет, код может на первый взгляд казаться одинаковым, но на самом деле он разный. Как минимум, в первом варианте отсутствует копирование. Во втором же варианте type punning отсутствует, поскольку мы не интерпретируем байты RECT по-другому, а напрямую копируем значение

Comment: @ComeInRage, вызывайте без копирования, оно ничего не изменит. Вы же просто передаете во внешнюю (ее код ваш компилятор не видит) функцию адрес и уже она интерпретирует как-то байты в памяти по этому адресу.

Comment: @avp и по-прежнему так и не получил ответа на вопрос)

Comment: Если игнорировать внутренности функции `MapWindowPoints`, то в первом варианте нет UB. Приведение к указателю на другой тип UB не вызывает, вызывает попытка обращения к значению через приведённый указатель и арифметика указателей над приведённым указателем, чего у вас в примере нет. Ещё могут быть проблемы с выравниванием, но в рамках WinAPI скорее всего гарантируется, что типы `RECT` и `POINT` имеют одинаковые требования по выравниванию, поэтому в этом плане здесь также нет проблем.

Comment: Остаётся только `MapWindowPoints` которая может внутри содержать UB код, но это не ваша проблема. Вряд ли компилятор в состоянии доказать её некорректность и использовать этот факт для некорректной оптимизации вашего кода.

Comment: Ну, и лично я не использовал бы ни приведение типа, ни `memcpy`, а просто скопировал обычным присвоением все необходимые поля `RECT` в массив `POINT`, а потом обратно. Так оно надёжнее всего :) Не думаю, что такое копирование будет критично в плане производительности.

Comment: Профайлера на Вас нет.

Comment: Миф как раз гласит, что можно, ничего не понимая, покрыть тестами неопределённости. И причём здесь вообще компилятор и переносимость?

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, что даже мелкомягкие знают свои типы и ничего опасного не накаламбурят. А глюки у них другие. И кто ж Вам-то разрешит код WinAPI менять?

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ.